# Extract field's names in R without reading the file

Tags: r, sf

I was wondering if it's possible to use the R package `sf` for extracting the names of the fields in a file without reading it. For example, I would like to replicate the following behaviour:

```r
system(paste0("ogrinfo -so ", system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), " nc"))
#> INFO: Open of `/home/andrea/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/sf/shape/nc.shp'
#>       using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

#> Layer name: nc
#> Metadata:
#>   DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2016-10-26
#> Geometry: Polygon
#> Feature Count: 100
#> Extent: (-84.323853, 33.881992) - (-75.456978, 36.589649)
#> Layer SRS WKT:
#> GEOGCRS["NAD27",
#>     DATUM["North American Datum 1927",
#>         ELLIPSOID["Clarke 1866",6378206.4,294.978698213898,
#>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
#>     PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
#>         ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#>     CS[ellipsoidal,2],
#>         AXIS["latitude",north,
#>             ORDER[1],
#>             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#>         AXIS["longitude",east,
#>             ORDER[2],
#>             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#>     ID["EPSG",4267]]
#> Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
#> AREA: Real (24.15)
#> PERIMETER: Real (24.15)
#> CNTY_: Real (24.15)
#> CNTY_ID: Real (24.15)
#> NAME: String (80.0)
#> FIPS: String (80.0)
#> FIPSNO: Real (24.15)
#> CRESS_ID: Integer (9.0)
#> BIR74: Real (24.15)
#> SID74: Real (24.15)
#> NWBIR74: Real (24.15)
#> BIR79: Real (24.15)
#> SID79: Real (24.15)
#> NWBIR79: Real (24.15)
```

without directly calling system or `ogrinfo`.

Comment: Do you just want the names of the fields or do you want all the other metadata (projection, geometry type, feature count etc) too?

Comment: Just the names of the fields since I need to check if some fields are already present in the file

Comment: You cannot read anything in any file with any app without reading the file.  Pedantry aside, it looks like what you want to do is essentially open the file, read the header & metadata, and then stop.  I think the posted answer is doing just that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use `st_read` with a query that selects zero rows you get back an empty dataframe with all the columns intact:

```
> nc_sql = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), query="select * from \"nc\" limit 0")

> dim(nc_sql)
[1]  0 15

> names(nc_sql)
 [1] "AREA"           "PERIMETER"      "CNTY_"          "CNTY_ID"       
 [5] "NAME"           "FIPS"           "FIPSNO"         "CRESS_ID"      
 [9] "BIR74"          "SID74"          "NWBIR74"        "BIR79"         
[13] "SID79"          "NWBIR79"        "_ogr_geometry_"
```

If you are also interested in the column types you can get those even though the data frame has no rows:

```
> class(nc_sql$FIPS)
[1] "factor"
> class(nc_sql$FIPSNO)
[1] "numeric"
```

and the projection:

```
> st_crs(nc_sql)
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: 4267 
  wkt:
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1927",
    DATUM["North_American_Datum_1927",
        SPHEROID["Clarke_1866",6378206.4,294.9786982]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4267"]]
```

I'm not sure if this counts as "without reading it", since at some level the code has to read the file. I don't think this reads the whole object and then drops all the rows, I think it is probably smart enough to stop after zero rows have been read. Would need to be tested to see how long it takes to read zero rows from a huge shapefile.

Another way which is basically wrapped around calling `ogrinfo` is to use the `gdalUtils` package:

```
> gdalUtils::ogrinfo(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"),al=TRUE,so=TRUE)
 [1] "INFO: Open of `/home/rowlings/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/sf/shape/nc.shp'"
 [2] "      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful."                                 
 [3] ""                                                                                
 [4] "Layer name: nc"                                                                  
 [5] "Metadata:"                                                                       
 [6] "  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2016-10-26"                                               
 [7] "Geometry: Polygon"                                                               
 [8] "Feature Count: 100"                                                              
 [9] "Extent: (-84.323853, 33.881992) - (-75.456978, 36.589649)"                       
[10] "Layer SRS WKT:"                                                                  
[11] "GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1927\","                                             
[12] "    DATUM[\"North_American_Datum_1927\","                                        
[13] "        SPHEROID[\"Clarke_1866\",6378206.4,294.9786982]],"                       
[14] "    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],"                                                    
[15] "    UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295],"                                      
[16] "    AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4267\"]]"                                               
[17] "AREA: Real (24.15)"                                                              
[18] "PERIMETER: Real (24.15)"                                                         
[19] "CNTY_: Real (24.15)"                                                             
[20] "CNTY_ID: Real (24.15)"                                                           
[21] "NAME: String (80.0)"                                                             
[22] "FIPS: String (80.0)"                                                             
[23] "FIPSNO: Real (24.15)"                                                            
[24] "CRESS_ID: Integer (9.0)"                                                         
[25] "BIR74: Real (24.15)"                                                             
[26] "SID74: Real (24.15)"                                                             
[27] "NWBIR74: Real (24.15)"                                                           
[28] "BIR79: Real (24.15)"                                                             
[29] "SID79: Real (24.15)"                                                             
[30] "NWBIR79: Real (24.15)"
```

but you'd then have to analyse the output carefully to find the lines of the field names.

Comment: Thank you very much! I checked the query approach with a 500MB gpkg file and it works perfectly. It takes approx 30 seconds to read the file and less than 0.1 seconds to read only the field names.